# Passing value from one child component to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

(using angular 1.5)

I have a parent component (main) passing an bunch of data to a child component (child1).

This child component (child1) displays the data in a table.  The rows of the table have an ng-click that stores a value when clicked (an integer).

here is the html of the main component:

```
<child2 sent-id = "$ctrl.sendCopy"></child2>

<child1 data = "$ctrl.stuff"></child1>
```

You can see child1 stores the stuff array as data (which is bound in the child 1 component)

I store the table value that is clicked like this:

```
function Child1Controller(){
  this.storeId = function(id){
   this.sendCopy = id;
 }
}
```

then in child2 I bind sentId like so

```
bindings: {
  sentId: '='
},
```

And just try to display it in the html but it isnt getting passed.

I feel like his is something really simple.
Thanks

EDIT (more code):
Child 1 component

```
angular.module('main').component('child1', {
templateUrl: 'scripts/components/child1.html',

bindings: {
 data: '<',
},
controller: Child1Controller
});

function Child1Controller($log){
 this.storeId = function(id){
  this.sendCopy = id;
 }
}
```

Child1 html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Id</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-click="$ctrl.storeId(data.id)"  ng-repeat="data in $ctrl.data | filter:data.name">
            <td>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.id}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Child2 component

```
angular.module('main').component('child2', {

  templateUrl: 'scripts/components/child2.html',

  bindings: {
    sentId: '='
  },

  controller: Child2Controller

});

function Child2Controller() {

}
```

Child2 html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
       ID = {{ $ctrl.sentId }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide more context?

Comment: can you post more code for your question

Comment: I updated my answer below based on your additional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child1 should not be an AngularJS Component because it modifies data outside of its scope. So I made that a directive. See documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

> Components only control their own View and Data: Components should
>   never modify any data or DOM that is out of their own scope. Normally,
>   in Angular it is possible to modify data anywhere in the application
>   through scope inheritance and watches. This is practical, but can also
>   lead to problems when it is not clear which part of the application is
>   responsible for modifying the data. That is why component directives
>   use an isolate scope, so a whole class of scope manipulation is not
>   possible.

Child2 can be a Component as shown below because it only displays data and doesn't update anything outside of its own scope.

See the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="main">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <child1 data="data" send-copy="myStore"></child1>
    <child2 sent-id="myStore"></child2>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('main',[]);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data=[
            {"name":"A","id":123},
            {"name":"B","id":456},
            {"name":"C","id":789}
        ];
    }]);

    app.controller('Child1Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.storeId = function(id){
            $scope.sendCopy = id;
        }
    }]);

    app.directive('child1',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body">' +
            '<table class="table table-hover">' +
            '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Id</th></tr></thead>' +
            '<tbody>' +
            '<tr ng-click="storeId(store.id)" ng-repeat="store in data">' +
            '<td>{{store.name}}</td><td>{{store.id}}</td></tr>' +
            '</tbody></table></div></div></div>',
            controller : "Child1Controller",
            scope: {
                data : "=",
                sendCopy : "="
            }
        };
    });

    app.component('child2', {
        template: '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
        '<div class="panel-body">' +
        '<div></div>' +
        '<div>ID = {{ $ctrl.sentId }}</div>' +
        '</div></div>',
        bindings: {
            sentId: '<'
        },
        controller: Child2Controller
    });

    // Controller for child2 Component
    function Child2Controller() {
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```